# Adding FlexLayoutModule coming up as undefined

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add FlexLayoutModule to a project, but it's coming up as undefined in the console.

I verified that in installed correctly and I can see it in my nodemodules folder. Here is what my ng.module.ts looks like:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';

import 'hammerjs';

/*----------  MODULES  ----------*/

export const modules = [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  MaterialModule.forRoot(),
  FlexLayoutModule.forRoot(),
  AppRoutingModule
];

/*----------  COMPONENTS  ----------*/

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {TopNavComponent} from './core/top-nav/top-nav.component';
import {NotificationsComponent} from './core/notifications/notifications.component';
import {ProfileComponent} from './profile/profile.component';
import {PageTitleComponent} from './shared/page-title/page-title.component';
import {SettingsComponent} from './settings/settings.component';
import {UserEditorComponent} from './settings/users/user-editor/user-editor.component';
import {UsersComponent} from './settings/users/users.component';
import {DeleteUserDialogComponent} from './settings/users/delete-user-dialog/delete-user-dialog.component';
import {TagsComponent} from './settings/tags/tags.component';


export const components = [
  AppComponent,
  TopNavComponent,
  ProfileComponent,
  NotificationsComponent,
  ProfileComponent,
  PageTitleComponent,
  SettingsComponent,
  UsersComponent,
  UserEditorComponent,
  DeleteUserDialogComponent,
  TagsComponent
];

/*----------  SERVICES  ----------*/

import {NotificationsService} from './core/notifications/notifications.service';
import {UsersService} from './settings/users/users.service';
import { CaseNavComponent } from './settings/case-nav/case-nav.component';

export const services = [
  NotificationsService,
  UsersService
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...components, CaseNavComponent],
  imports: [...modules],
  providers: [...services],
  entryComponents: [DeleteUserDialogComponent], // for angular material 2
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

The error Im getting in the console is that this line in the module's constant array is undefined, though I clearly have it imported:        FlexLayoutModule.forRoot(),

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added the map dependency in system.config.js something like '@angular/flex-layout': 'npm:@angular/flex-layout/bundles/*.umd.js' ?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Angular 2, transitioning form 1.x. I used the @angular/cli to build the project. I don't see a system.config.js in the project root or subfolder...

Comment: Try without .forRoot(), those are not needed anymore. Considering your packages are up to date.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is with the FlexLayoutModule being undefined. So removing that still has that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was incorrect import path.